# Cpanel CronJob several days of the week

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am new to cron jobs, and I want to run a script on several days of the week

I did create a CronJob but it didn't run last night.
I want to execute the script every night at 00:10 on Sunday through thursday

So I added this as the Job
`10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4 execute.php`

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"it didn't run last night"*; did it ever run, apart from yesterday?

Comment: Nope fairly not. I know the script works if I approach it directly. I just want to have the cronjob to load the page so the script will execute

Comment: Tell me more about your system. OS? Folder/file in which this cron is set? Etc. Maybe you are missing the bin and username, but it depends on system. Try, for example: `10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4 root /usr/bin/php execute.php`

Comment: The server runs`Linux` and the folder: `/public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php`

Comment: I ran the cronjob like this just to see if it excecutes but nothing... `*  *  *  *  *  root /usr/bin/php /public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php`

Comment: Try remove `root`: `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php`. Anyway I dubt you have a root folder `/public_html` on your server. Maybe the full path is different, for example `/home/user/public_html` or `/var/www/public_html`. Try to find it out.

Comment: If I create an error the path is: `/home/username/public_html/url.nl/execute.php`. My FTP sais: `/www/url.nl/execute.php`

Comment: I did some internetsearching while waiting :-) and this seems to work: `php -f /home/user/public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php` Can you tell me what the -f means? Thnx big time for your help!

Comment: `-f` is an optional parameter. If it works with it, it will work also without it. At least seems you have found the correct path of your file. Try: `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php`

Comment: I gave `usr/bin/php` a try but that didn't work. It run's now. Every minute my script got executed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well the test failed. "Last night" I wanted to execute the script at 00:10. The script mails me if executed. I didn't get an email this morning. If I use `* * * * * php -f /home/usr/public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php` it sends me an email every minute. If I use `10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4 php -f /home/usr/public_html/xxx.nl/execute.php` it doesn't run. Can you/anybody spot a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to run daily and just add this to the top of your script

```
if (date('l') == 'Friday' || date('l') == 'Saturday') exit;
```

That way it won't even do anything unless it's a day you require and saves you a headache.

Comment: That is a PHP solution and I'm looking for a cronjob solution

Comment: Fair enough, but still looking for cronjob thnx!

Answer (score 0):

**root user on shell (WHM/Cpanel over Centos)**

```
# crontab -e  #Edit cron jobs for user root

10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /full/path/to/execute.php >/dev/null 2>&1  #If not like report to email
```

**user cpanel**
with shell acces

```
$ crontab -e  #Edit cron jobs for user

10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /full/path/to/execute.php >/dev/null 2>&1  #If not like report to email 

or

10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4  /usr/bin/php /full/path/to/execute.php >/dev/null 2>&1  #If not like report to email
```

without shell access

```
Enter Cpanel and go to Cronjobs.
Put your tiem on each text input area.
Put your job 10 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /full/path/to/execute.php >/dev/null 2>&1  #If not like report to email
```

**Explanations**

/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php PHP compiled for WHM/Cpanel functions.

/usr/bin/php PHP used by **normal** Cpanel installation

It's possible other paths if your server used for example, Couldlinux with multiples PHP versions.